# Using meta data refresh on mvc

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to redirect page after form being submited after 3 seconds

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"/>
```

This doesnt work

Comment: How is your form being submit?

Comment: @Rory HttpPost action

Comment: In that case you need to use AJAX to make the form submission so you can stay on the current page for a few seconds after the request completes and then redirect in JS.

Comment: @Rory There is no other soultion?!!  meta tag is working when i use url="google.com" it direct me to google.com, i want it to direct me to action

Comment: That meta tag is used to redirect after 3 seconds regardless of the form being submit.

Comment: @Rory oh thats right

Comment: @Rory What about this??  $("form").submit(function (e)
            {
                alert("hi")
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = "www.google.com"
                }, 5000);

                })
Its not working too

Comment: That won't work reliably as most browsers prevent further JS execution once a request to unload the page has been made. AJAX is the most easily workable solution.

Comment: @Rory Is There an example Where i can achieve this using ajax?